# What is the meaning of r in REGEXP_EXTRACT(word,r'(\w\w\'\w\w)')

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I can't find an answer in either BigQuery [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) or re2 [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/re2/).

In all the examples for Regex section in the BigQuery Reference there is an 'r' before every regex, but I can't find anywhere the meaning of it. For example:

REGEXP_EXTRACT(word,r'(\w\w\'\w\w)')

It seems to me as a typecast of 'regex' or something, because it allows for '\' and ''' in the following string.

Thanks to anyone who knows and posts an answer to this :)

Comment: Search for "raw string" - at least that's what it means in Python.

Answer (score 14):

From Wikipedia "A few languages provide a method of specifying that a literal is to be processed without any language-specific interpretation. This avoids the need for escaping, and yields more legible strings."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings

For example, this looks like a valid regex, but the escapes get miss-interpreted:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT("ab'cd", '(\w\w\'\w\w)') 

Error: Invalid string literal: '(\w\w\'\w\w)'
```

I can fix this in two ways. With a raw string, or escaping the escapes:

Escaping the escapes:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT("ab'cd", '(\\w\\w\'\\w\\w)')
ab'cd
```

Raw string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT("ab'cd", r'(\w\w\'\w\w)')
ab'cd
```