# Saving string as regular expression in Google BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I need to classify values of column by few of regular expressions. I'm using regex_contains. I would like to get new parameter depending of the answer (true|false). I have another table, there is 2 columns: regular expressions and parameters.
I joined  the tables like that:
`select * from xxx join yyy on REGEXP_CONTAINS(xxx.value, yyy.regExVal) = true`

How can I put regular expression as the string? I need save 'r' litera in front of exact regular expresion. 
`REGEXP_CONTAINS(VALUE, r'REGEX')`
Or maybe anyone knows how to store regular expressions as the values in another bigquery-table?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression has to be saved as raw strings.

[What is the meaning of r in REGEXP_EXTRACT(word,r'(\w\w\'\w\w)')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829101/what-is-the-meaning-of-r-in-regexp-extractword-r-w-w-w-w)

```
WITH xxx AS (
  SELECT 'alpha' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'gamma' UNION ALL
  SELECT  '123'
  ),
  yyy as (Select "[0-9]" regExVal UNION ALL Select r"\w")
 

select *, REGEXP_extract(xxx.value, yyy.regExVal) as found
 from xxx join yyy on REGEXP_CONTAINS(xxx.value, yyy.regExVal) = true
```

see the `r` in `r"\w"`